# Issue with Service Bus Queue Trigger: Messages not triggering endpoints

Tags: c#, queue, azureservicebus

We have implemented a system where we send data from one service to another using a Service Bus queue. However, we are facing an intermittent issue where the messages sent to the queue do not trigger the corresponding endpoints. We have configured the system as follows:

Message sending implementation:

```
using Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus;

public class AzureServiceBusMessageSender : IMessageSender
{
    private readonly ServiceBusSender serviceBusSender;

    public AzureServiceBusMessageSender(string connectionString, string queueName)
    {
        var queueClient = new ServiceBusClient(connectionString);
        serviceBusSender = queueClient.CreateSender(queueName);
    }

    public async Task<Response<SendReceipt>> SendAsync<TRunParameters>(TRunParameters message)
    {
        await serviceBusSender.SendMessageAsync(message.ToServiceBusMessage());
        return null;
    }
}
```

Message receiving implementation using ServiceBusTrigger attribute:

```
[ServiceBusTrigger(nameof(DataAcquisitionJob), Connection = "ServiceBusConnectionString", IsSessionsEnabled = true)]
public void ProcessMessage([ServiceBusMessage] string message, ILogger logger)
{
    // Endpoint processing logic
    // ...
}
```

Configuration in local.settings.json:

```
{
    "IsEncrypted": false,
    "Values": {
        "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
        "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet-isolated",
        "ServiceBusConnectionString": "bus.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=RootManageSharedAccessKey;SharedAccessKey=###"
    }
}
```

We have also configured certain settings in the Service Bus queue, as shown in the following image.

[image]

**Issue Description:**
After sending messages to the queue, we noticed that sometimes the messages do not trigger the endpoints, and no logs are inserted into our log file. We have also checked the Dead-Letter Queue, but the messages are not present there either. This issue occurs sporadically and not consistently.

We would greatly appreciate any assistance in resolving this problem.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Are you sure that you're not seeing errors when sending?  It looks like you're creating the ServiceBusClient and then throwing it away.  The client owns the connection used by the sender.  If the instance is claimed by GC due to going out of scope, it will tear down the connection and your sender will be in a failed state and unable to recover.

Comment: Azure Service Bus queue sending and receiving message [reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-dotnet-get-started-with-queues?tabs=passwordless)

Comment: null messages in the active message count due to messages which are sent is received by receiving a trigger. but the incoming message changes.

Answer (score 0):

Service Bus Queue Messages not triggering (or) Null messages in the `active message count` may be due to messages which are sent being received by receiving a trigger but the `incoming message` changes. The One of reasons we are able to see the Null Messages is due to the receiving trigger with an end being active. The message will be triggered to Receiving trigger. We could check the incoming message count if the message came or not.

[image]

- Sample Reference Code taken from [Azure Service Bus queues](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-dotnet-get-started-with-queues?tabs=passwordless).

**Sending  message:**

[image]

[image]

**Receiving the message:**

- In Azure [Portal](https://i.imgur.com/xsahq8e.png).

**In visual studio:**

[image]

[image]

- For sending a message refer to this [AzureServiceBusqueues](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-dotnet-get-started-with-queues?tabs=passwordless).